# PostgresSQL 9.4.5.1 "You are trying to run a 64bit installer in a 32bit machine" bitrock_installer.log

Tags: postgresql-9.4

PostgreSQL is packaged with our application. I have a expect script to connect to remote machine a Windows 64 bit VM. I open a ssh session from a Linux box to windows and try to extract postgresql9.4.5.1 for installation I get the following error in bitrock_installer.log "You are trying to run a 64bit installer in a 32bit machine" which I never experienced with the lower version

Comment: The error message is pretty clear I'd say: your Windows VM is **not** a 64bit Windows.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to add this. I am able to install the same locally with no errors

Comment: Then apparently your _local_ computer is a 64bit Windows

Comment: I meant that is the windows VM

Comment: But you said you can **not** run the installer in the Windows VM.

Comment: Besides it worked for postgresql-8.x

Comment: I have a Windows 64 bit VM. when I try to SSH from Linux box to this Windows VM and execute the commandf to install the application in silent mode it extracts postgresql.9.4.5 and will install the same. Without SSH from Linux Box if I try to execute from Windows VM it extracts and installs successfully. The script that I am using was working for 8.x

Comment: Log started 01/04/2016 at 02:36:04
Preferred installation mode : unattended
Trying to init installer in mode unattended
Mode unattended successfully initialized
There has been an error.
You are trying to run a 64bit installer in a 32bit machine. The installer will exit now, I am sure that the VM is 64bit from the VM I am opening a SSH tunnel to install is also a 64 bit VM

Answer (score 0):

I have seen such behavior many times when trying to install Postgres x64 onto MS Azure VM (and YES, it was x64 VM version as it had 56Gb memory).

UPDATE

EnterpriseDB was confident that they produce valid installers and has recommended to check Azure settings. Resolution for me was changing Virtual machine instance size in Azure managemnt console and rebooting it. The same binary throwing "You are trying to run a 64bit installer..." worked just fine after changing instance type to A1 standard. For reference, binary i was using was postgresql-9.6.0-beta1-windows-x64.exe
So folks, don't waste your time raging against Enterprisedb or sitting in debugger. Just temporarily change your Azure instance size if you are experiencing this problem.